# Use a specific database depending on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I somehow use a specific database given a specific condition? To clarify I will give a naive example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @dbnum = 1 THEN USE Db1
        ELSE USE DefaultDb
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with an IF:

```
IF @dbnum = 1
    USE Db1;
ELSE
    USE DefaultDb;
```

Comment: Superb, thanks! @OMG Ponies could  you explain that statement? When to use it and when not to.

Comment: Quite alright. CASE should be used _within_ a query to put a conditional on individual values of a column (from the SELECT, ORDER or GROUP), IF is used _outside_ individual queries, to determine which queries should be run.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me